# Adding intent to MainActivity results in "No Launcher activity found"

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to add a new action to the MainActivity intent-filter in the Manifest, like this:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.packagename.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <action android:name="com.packagename.SET_ALARM" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

But this results in the console giving the message "No Launcher activity found" when I try to reinstall the app, even though both MAIN- and LAUNCHER-actions are included. Any ideas?

Comment: What is telling you "No Launcher activity found"? Also, could you please post the entire `<activity>` element?

Comment: Fixed the original post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unlikely that this `<intent-filter>` is what you want. This will respond to either `MAIN` or `SET_ALARM`, with the `LAUNCHER` category. IOW, to use `SET_ALARM`, you would have to use:

```
 new Intent("com.packagename.SET_ALARM").addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
```

It is unlikely that any third-party app would ever use such an `Intent`. And if this is for your own app, please use an explicit `Intent` (e.g., `new Intent(this, MainActivity.class)`) and get rid of `SET_ALARM` entirely. **Only** add custom actions when you want third-party apps to be able to reference your component (and then, only if you are not supplying them with a `PendingIntent` to work with).

If you really do want that `SET_ALARM` to be used by third-party applications, you probably want:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.packagename.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />

        <action android:name="com.packagename.SET_ALARM" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

All that being said, I am not quite certain why Eclipse was unhappy.